# C++ Making a thread and passing Object by reference

Tags: c++, multithreading

Currently trying to pass an object by reference to another thread but I get errors when I try to build my solution.

```
void OrderServer(Orders& customerOrders)
{
    Item tempItem;
    customerOrders.add(tempItem);
}

int main()
{
Orders customerOrders();
auto serverThread = std::thread(OrderServer, std::cref(customerOrders));
serverThread.detach();
return 0;
}
```

The following is the error:

c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\thr\xthread(240): error C2672: 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\thr\xthread(248): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Execute<0,1>(std::tuple> &,std::integer_sequence<_Ty,0,1>)' being compiled

Comment: You are passing a `std::cref` to a non-constant parameter function. Try passing `std::ref()` or making your function accept a `const` parameter reference.

Comment: Your thread function accepts by a non-const reference. But you create a const reference wrapper with `std::cref`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Orders customerOrders();` declares a function. This is known as the most-vexing parse.

You can simply use `Orders customerOrders;`

Comment: But you still have UB

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this, what does UB mean?

Comment: Undefined Behavior (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior))

Answer (score 0):

You could try simply:

```
auto serverThread = std::thread(OrderServer, customerOrders);
```

(and as [told by François Moisan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47766386/841108) you have a typo when declaring `customerOrders`).

without any `std::cref`. However, your thread is later detached, but the `customerOrders` is destroyed by the return of `main`. That is probably an [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since `OrderServer` then works with a reference to some object which does not exist anymore.

Comment: You need to take the habit to trust your compiler, enable all warnings in it, and correct your code to get no warnings. That should be quite easy.